# What are the economic benefits to create an owned blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, migration

Lot of entity on Ethereum have decided to create their own blockchain and migrate there.

What I can't find online is **what are economical advantages** on doing this.

Is it related solely to a cheaper gas cost factor or is there more?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks my question is related to "economic benefits" in details only, so it's completely different

Comment: Understood. In the second answer on that question (i.e. the highest-voted, but not accepted) there are various economic arguments put forward. They might cover at least part of what you're after.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Yes indeed but for example this answer "for many smaller applications, use of an existing public blockchain will provide more security per dollar spent compared to constructing and maintaining a private chain" is not detailed for me. It would be nice to have real data to compare

Comment: Okay, understood. I'll be interested to see the answers you get.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks :D probably none

Comment: I think it's probably likely that no one (or very few people) has that level of detail :-)